# Problemas com JSON + PHP

Tags: php, json, aplicação-web

Possuo um arquivo **JSON** que está sendo utilizado para armazenar configurações, e um arquivo **php**, que lê e preenche o arquivo de acordo com os dados informados, entretanto após as configurações serem editadas por muitas vezes o **JSON** está tem seu formato alterado de **Array** para **Objeto**:

Formato necessário:

```
{"favoritesIndex":[28,22,133,38,12,27]}
```

Formato gerado:

```
{"favoritesIndex":{"1":28,"2":22,"3":133,"4":38,"5":12,"6":27}}
```

Codigo PHP:

```
function read() {return json_decode(file_get_contents('sec_settings/datatable.json'));}
function write($data){return file_put_contents('sec_settings/datatable.json',json_encode($data));}

function setFavorite()
{
    $settings = read();
    $settings->favoritesIndex[] = (int) $_REQUEST['id'];
    $settings = write($settings);
}

function removeFavorite()
{
    $settings = read();

    foreach($settings->favoritesIndex AS $key => $value)
        if($_REQUEST['id'] == $value)
            unset($settings->favoritesIndex[$key]);

    $settings = write($settings);
}

try
{
    if(isset($_REQUEST['fn'])) $_REQUEST['fn']();
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    die("Could not process requested operation, {$e}");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que isto ocorra quando os indexes deixam de ser sequencial, assim sendo necessário ser um objeto para que continue com os mesmos indexes.

Para exemplo considere isso:

```
$json = json_decode('{"favoritesIndex":[28,22,133,38,12,27]}');

unset($json->favoritesIndex[5]);

echo json_encode($json);
```

O retorno será `{"favoritesIndex":[28,22,133,38,12]}`, por que o `5` é o último valor, por isso ainda continua sendo de `0` até `4`.

Porém, se remover qualquer um, que não seja o último:

```
$json = json_decode('{"favoritesIndex":[28,22,133,38,12,27]}');

unset($json->favoritesIndex[1]); // Remover o 22, o segundo valor

echo json_encode($json);
```

Você irá criar uma lacuna (existindo valor `0` e `2` até `5`), assim terá como resultado `{"favoritesIndex":{"0":28,"2":133,"3":38,"4":12,"5":27}}`, devido a falta do `1`, que foi removido.

---

Então você precisa recriar a array do PHP, de maneira que sempre esteja em ordem, sem nenhuma lacuna, isso pode ser feito da seguinte maneira:

```
$settings['favoritesIndex'] = array_values($settings['favoritesIndex']);
```

No caso ficaria alguma próxima a isso:

```
function read() {return json_decode(file_get_contents('sec_settings/datatable.json'), true);}
function write($data){return file_put_contents('sec_settings/datatable.json',json_encode($data));}


function setFavorite(int $valor)
{
    $settings = read();
    $settings['favoritesIndex'][] = $valor;
    $settings = write($settings);
}

function removeFavorite(int $valor)
{
    $settings = read();

    $achado = array_search($valor, $settings['favoritesIndex']);
    if($achado !== false){
        unset($settings['favoritesIndex'][$achado]);
    }

    $settings['favoritesIndex'] = array_values($settings['favoritesIndex']);

    $settings = write($settings);
}
```

Note que existem mudanças (como usar `array` com o `json_decode(..., true)`, o valor é informado como um parâmetro na função...), isso foi feito unicamente para que pudesse testar mais rápido, [como pode ver aqui funcionamento](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/491a8c6d92ec75e3e6d2040982155c82d3722302).

Answer (score 1):

Ele está colocando um indice natural na array, e você está tentando acessar uma chave que não é chave, método errado:

```
function setFavorite()
{
    $settings = read();
    //Essa abertura [] indica para preencher o indice de acordo com o loop e gera uma chave sequencial
    $settings->favoritesIndex[] = (int) $_REQUEST['id'];
    $settings = write($settings);
}
```

Faça isso, tornando o indice o próprio valor:

```
function setFavorite()
{
    $settings = read();
    $ID = (int) $_REQUEST['id'];

    $settings->favoritesIndex[$ID];
    $settings = write($settings);
}
```

Acredito que isso vá solucionar, só está errado as posições na construção da array.

Comment: Sim, a posição tem de ser sequencial pois vários valores serão incluídos no array de forma dinâmica, e pode me explicar melhor sobre tornar o índice o próprio valor? Testei teu trecho, e acusou um erro de posicionamento.

Comment: Se você precisa disso: {"favoritesIndex":[28,22,133,38,12,27]}, e esses números são o ID., você precisa colocar os ids como chaves um nivel acima de favoritesIndex, igual no exemplo, pra sequenciar, você não vai ter essas chaves, vai ter o exemplo que você disse que tem agora. Qual o erro que aponta ?

Comment: Undefined offset: 28

Comment: Ve se está construindo certo, da um var_dump() na array do objeto favoriteIndex e ve se ela está no formato correto

Comment: Esse erro Undefined offset: 28 vem do foreach do segundo metodo, é isso ? porque ele não encontra o $key em favoritesIndex

Comment: Não, é gerado pelo $settings->favoritesIndex[$ID];

Comment: Diz uma coisa pra eu entender, $settings->favoriteIndex seria um método ? Isso está dentro de uma classe ? se não precisar da instancia, você salva em uma array sem objeto $settings[$ID], e passa essa array para o write() ja que a chave vai ser sempre favoriteIndex, ou $settings['favoriteIndex'][$ID]

Comment: //inclui o conteudo json na variavel
        $settings = read();
        //$settings->indice json
        $settings->favoritesIndex[] = x;
        //reescreve o json no arquivo
        $settings = write($settings);

Comment: Se você manter uma chave aberta '[ ]', sem exceção, ele vai sequenciar, e sua resposta vai ser algo como  {"indice":{"1":"valor 1", "2":"valor 2"}}, você precisa fazer com que $ID vá dentro de [ ] , pra que você tenha: {"indice":{"valor 1", "valor 2"}}, sacou ? você só ta errando o lugar da chave, pode reescrever com array, não precisa desse objeto aberto em write, chama direto, $array['favoriteIndex'][$ID], mas se estiver dentro de uma classe, ai muda um pouco

Comment: Cara, definindo a chave como sequencial, eu estou dizendo que quero que esse valor sempre seja adicionado como um novo índice!

Comment: Isso {"indice":{"1":"valor 1", "2":"valor 2"}} estaria definindo o array como um objeto, o que pra mim não é útil

Comment: Cara, o problema está no unset na função removeFavorite()

Comment: Entendi agora, só diz mais uma coisa e ja vou saber o que é o problema, da um var_dump($settings) depois do read no primeiro método 'setFavorite' e também no segundo 'removeFavorite', e coloca a resposta aqui, agora que acho que entendi, to achando que o erro ta nesse acesso '->' porque você ja deu o decode, podes acessar com $settings['favoritesIndex'], ai sim você vai ter essa resposta que você quer, só responde esse var_dump aqui e ja vamos saber se é isso mesmo

Comment: function removeFavorite()
    {
        $settings = read();

        foreach($settings->favoritesIndex AS $key => $value)
        {
            if($_REQUEST['id'] == $value) unset($settings->favoritesIndex[$key]);
        }

        $settings->favoritesIndex = array_values($settings->favoritesIndex);
        
        write($settings);
    }

Comment: O que é isso ? eu preciso da resposta do var_dump($settings), pra saber como ele está dentro do target pra poder te ajudar, não do método em si

Comment: Já foi resolvido, o problema estava na função removeFavorite.

Comment: Obrigado pela Ajuda!

Comment: Ah , entendi que vc tinha postado um comentário errado ali em cima kk blzz, posta a solução numa resposta, acho que é uma duvida que mais gente pode ter